# Iterating over collections in Java

Tags: java, iterator

The following code gives an exception, however, I do not understand why.

```
List suits = ...;
List ranks = ...;
List sortedDeck = new ArrayList();

// BROKEN - throws NoSuchElementException!
for (Iterator i = suits.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
    for (Iterator j = ranks.iterator(); j.hasNext(); )
        sortedDeck.add(new Card(i.next(), j.next()));
```

The solution is apparently as follows:

```
// Fixed, though a bit ugly
for (Iterator i = suits.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Suit suit = (Suit) i.next();
    for (Iterator j = ranks.iterator(); j.hasNext(); )
        sortedDeck.add(new Card(suit, j.next()));
}
```

I understand why the solution works, but why doesn't the first example work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just understood why! It's simply because `i.next()` ends up being called too many times due to the nested for-loop. It is only meant to access one suit, the same suit, for each group of 'j' iterations. Hence, the `i.next()` is called **outside** the nested loop to prevent the suit from changing every single time.

Answer (score -2):

You forgot using the brackets `{}` in your first block.

```js
List suits = ...;
List ranks = ...;
List sortedDeck = new ArrayList();

// BROKEN - throws NoSuchElementException!
for (Iterator i = suits.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    for (Iterator j = ranks.iterator(); j.hasNext(); )
        sortedDeck.add(new Card(i.next(), j.next()));
}
```

Comment: I hope you realise that it is perfectly permissible to omit the braces if there is  only one statement within!